# Redirect to pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I currently have this:

```
redirect 301 ^/about/ /about.html
redirect 301 ^/about/skills/ /skills.html
redirect 301 ^/about/experience/ /experience.html
redirect 301 ^/about/projects/ /projects.html
```

I want to redirect `/about/` to `about.html`, `/about/skills/` to `/skills.html`

But the above `redirect`s don't work and are still going to `/about/`

What should be my `redirect 301` be?

Note that these ones are below my redirects:

```
# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(system) - [F,L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) does not allow you to specify a regex.

One way to do this is to add the rules below to your .htaccess, ahead of your existing rules.

```
RewriteRule ^about/$ /about.html [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^about/skills/$ /skills.html [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule  ^about/experience/$ /experience.html [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^about/projects/$ /projects.html [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: There's still one problem. `/about` isn't redirected. only `/about/` was. What would I do to include `/about`?

Comment: a quick fix I did was `^(/about/|about)$ /about.html [NC, R=301, L]` but is there a better way?

Comment: @ThorpeObazee to make the trailing slash optional use a `?` ie `^about/?$ /about.html [NC,R=301,L]`